# enviar valor a un trait desde use de una clase

Tags: php, symfony2, doctrine2

Tengo una clase `Printer` que utiliza un `Trait` llamado `TagTrait`.
quiero enviar un valor desde la clase que utiliza dicho trait para que el trait defina una relación de una tabla en doctrine según me interese.

Ejemplo:

```
class Printer 
{
    use TagTrait; // aqui hacer algo para enviar el texto "printer"
    // .. varios metodos

}


use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

trait TagTrait
{

       /**
       * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Tag", cascade={"persist"})
       * @ORM\JoinTable(
       *      name= "Parametro_enviado_desde_clase",
       *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name=Parametro_enviado_desde_clase."_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
       *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
       * )
       */
   protected $tags;


    // .. varios metodos
}
```

La idea es que el trait defina la propiedad `$tags` como una relación manytomany sobre otra entidad, pero que la tabla intermedia tenga el nombre que le he enviado desde el trait.

Si fuera posible, se podría definir este trait de tipo general y solo tendría que hacer un use indicando el parámetro para que el doctrine realizara sus operaciones sobre las tablas que me interesan.

¿Alguien sabe si puede hacerse algo como esto?

La única solución que encuentro es sacar todo el código del trait y ponerlo en la entidad printer, puesto que no logro pasar ese parámetro...

Comment: Igual me equivoco, pero esto no creo que pueda hacerse. Ten en cuenta que no es posible pasar valores a los metadatos de las anotaciones. Lo único que se me ocurre es que uses el trait para generar los métodos, y definas la relación tag en cada entidad.

Comment: gracias Muriano. En este caso te contradigo: se pueden pasar parametros a los metadatos de las anotaciones. es posible definir el name del JoinTable como  TagTrait::class y la tabla se crea como el namespace\TagTrait. (por supuesto esto ultimo es incorrecto, pero permite un cierto dinamismo). Tengo un intento de ejemplo en el grupo https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/symfony-es/SZrBk6s8k7Y, para intentar explicarlo mejor.

Comment: Lo desconocía completamente. Siendo así, es posible hacer lo mismo, por ejemplo, usando `static::TABLE_NAME`, donde TABLE_NAME es una constante definida en la clase (no en el trait) ??

Answer (score 0):

Me respondo a mi mismo. En el grupo de google https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/symfony-es/SZrBk6s8k7Y me han dado la respuesta que buscaba... Lo unico que hay que hacer es quitar el campo name en la definicion de la relacion en el trait:

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

```
trait TagTrait
{

       /**
       * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\ClassificationBundle\Entity\Tag", cascade={"persist"})
       * @ORM\JoinTable(
       *      name= "Parametro_enviado_desde_clase",
       *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name=Parametro_enviado_desde_clase."_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
       *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
       * )
       */
   protected $tags;


    // .. varios metodos
}
```

Con esto, doctrine intenta crear la tabla printer_tag:

```
CREATE TABLE printer_tag (printer_id INT NOT NULL, tag_id INT NOT NULL, INDEX IDX_FE129BD746EC494A (printer_id), INDEX IDX_FE129BD7BAD26311 (tag_id), PRIMARY KEY(printer_id, tag_id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE printer_tag ADD CONSTRAINT FK_FE129BD746EC494A FOREIGN KEY (printer_id) REFERENCES printer (id);
ALTER TABLE printer_tag ADD CONSTRAINT FK_FE129BD7BAD26311 FOREIGN KEY (tag_id) REFERENCES classification__tag (id);
```

Si la relacion fuera con otra entidad, por ej, Collection, doctrine intenta crear la tabla printer_collection:

> CREATE TABLE printer_collection (printer_id INT NOT NULL, tag_id INT
>   NOT NULL, INDEX IDX_8963B5A046EC494A (printer_id), INDEX
>   IDX_8963B5A0BAD26311 (tag_id), PRIMARY KEY(printer_id, tag_id))
>   DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB;
>   ALTER TABLE printer_collection ADD CONSTRAINT FK_8963B5A046EC494A
>   FOREIGN KEY (printer_id) REFERENCES printer (id); ALTER TABLE
>   printer_collection ADD CONSTRAINT FK_8963B5A0BAD26311 FOREIGN KEY
>   (tag_id) REFERENCES classification__collection (id);

Es decir, omitiendo el name de doctrine, nos intenta crear una tabla con el nombre de la clase, _ y el nombre de la entidad relacionada :)